# Module importation error, using Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I followed [google colab module import](https://www.pingshiuanchua.com/blog/post/importing-your-own-python-module-or-python-file-in-colaboratory) but i keep on getting the error "No module name 'mymodule'".[image: Error, no module found]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to import your own module on google colab, relative imports wouldn't work so you will have to import the module by providing full path like this

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
module = SourceFileLoader("mymodule", "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/mymodule.py").load_module()
```

Comment: Ok, got it...but on colab the python extension is "ipynb", that worked.